# How to find a keyboard shortcut, globally: ctrl-shift-P

Tags: 13.10, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I've been using Sublime for quite some time now and bringing up the palate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> has always been my go to shortcut. All this in Ubuntu 13.10.

However, I recently lost the ability to use this anymore and had to change it to Q instead of P. Now, I tried looking for shortcuts and seeing if something is overriding it but can't seem to do so. Is there any way, other than uninstalling everything, to find this assignment?

If anyone knows of a program which uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> as a shortcut, please let me know.

Comment: ctrl-shift-P seems to be "print to file" for various random applications, and defined somewhere unfindable in Gnome.  At least, I spent over an hour trying to find it withough success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you don't have to uninstall everything, just do not launch anything.

1. Just restart and close all the applications that started up with the system. Application global shortcuts won't work if the application is not running.
2. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to be sure this is an application global shortcut and not a system shortcut
3. Then, launch one by one and check if the global shortcut occurs (by pressing the keys while not focusing the launched application in order to be sure the shortcut is global).