# How to change keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm new to Linux and I am having trouble with Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between applications and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change the keyboard layout.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Alt-Tab seems to work OK by default. I wonder if you're having another problem. As for changing the keyboard layout (and shortcut), look in System Settings -> Text Entry.

Comment: What exactly is the trouble you are having?

Answer (score 58):

### On Unity (up to Ubuntu 17.10)

To see Unity shortcuts press and hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

To customize shortcuts open *System settings* (`gnome-control-center`), go to *Keyboard* and select the *Shortcuts* tab. Explore all the categories to find what you're interested in changing and click on it to change. Then press the keys for your new shortcut.

[image: customize shortcuts]

To change the keyboard layout shortcut, in *System settings* go to *Text Entry* and change the shortcuts there.

[image: change the keyboard layout shortcut]

Comment: Here's a question: Under Keyboard > Shortcuts, the shortcut for "Key to show the HUD" was "Alt L". I confirmed that just tapping the left Alt key would bring it up. But when I changed it to something else, I couldn't change it back. What's the magic for specifying a modifier key as a shortcut?

Answer (score 19):

Some of the shortcuts are impossible to change with built-in system settings GUI. Most other system-wide shortcuts are modified through `dconf` as [described here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings).

- Open Terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by default)
- `sudo apt install dconf-editor`
- `dconf-editor`
- Navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`
- Further setup is obvious, except for [<Primary>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168505/what-is-primary-for-a-key).

---

The figure below is the example to disable <kbd>Alt + F7</kbd>:

[image: Example-to-disable-ALT-F7]

Comment: is it also changes `XKBOPTIONS="grp:` from `/etc/default/keyboard` ? I doubt that .

Comment: Don't forget to check if the shortcut is also used in unity options

Answer (score 12):

### On Ubuntu 18.04 and later

1. Launch **Settings**
2. Click on **Devices** (under Network)
3. Click on **Keyboard**

[image]
[image]

If you want to add a custom shortcut scroll to the bottom of the applet and click on the `+` symbol to create a shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Wow. That is extremely well obfuscated. Why is the keyboard shortcut editor (the one shown above, which works) under "Wired Settings"? The "help" leads you to the one under the regular settings (which is hidden under a hamburger menu and not in the list, as the help says), and that one is basically useless (AFAICT it just shows a dialog with four shotcuts that you can't change). This is for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.