# After upgrading to 14.04 arrow down doesn't work / action seems to be wrongly assigned on Xserver

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, keyboard, xorg, settings

after upgrading to 14.04 (from 12.04) the down arrow is not working properly anymore on graphical system. On console the key works fine, but not on terminal (within X). Unfortunately I didn't found the answer by searching on Internet, maybe I'm looking for the wrong tags/ key words. However, I found some hints to check the button behavior with `xev`. The result of the key sequence arrow left, up, right and down is shown here:

```
    KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     root 0x283, subw 0x0, time 141793, (-397,1002), root:(390,1054),
     state 0x0, keycode 113 (keysym 0xff51, Left), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False

 KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     root 0x283, subw 0x0, time 141974, (-397,1002), root:(390,1054),
     state 0x0, keycode 113 (keysym 0xff51, Left), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False

 KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     root 0x283, subw 0x0, time 142807, (-397,1002), root:(390,1054),
     state 0x0, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False

 KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     root 0x283, subw 0x0, time 142949, (-397,1002), root:(390,1054),
     state 0x0, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False

 KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     root 0x283, subw 0x0, time 149744, (-397,1002), root:(390,1054),
     state 0x0, keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False

 KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     root 0x283, subw 0x0, time 149895, (-397,1002), root:(390,1054),
     state 0x0, keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False

 FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

 FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

 KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
     keys:  4294967171 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

 KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
     root 0x283, subw 0x0, time 150559, (-397,1002), root:(390,1054),
     state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
     XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As you may see, the arrow down behavior is different, but does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the down arrow key was set to "show Desktop".

Having figured this out I was able to unset it.

For those who struggle on a similar problem you may find this page helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings. At least it solved my problem.

[how to change keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts)