# I cant find terminal?

Tags: command-line

So I am new to ubuntu,and I was trying many things last night and I dont know what I did but there is no terminal anymore. I pres ctrl+alt+T but it opens a program name Xterm. I don't know if this is the same or not and if I can use it like the terminal I use before.

I feel like my question is really stupid but as I said I'm new and I'm trying to learn. Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not the same; does running `gnome-terminal` in XTerm opens the "old" terminal?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

Comment: Sounds like you need to change your keyboard shortcut to the terminal to go to the `gnome-terminal` instead of `xterm`.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the application explorer which is in top left corner. The in search field, type "terminal". It will show up the terminal application icon, click on it.