# KDE 5.24 defaults to Konsole even if Terminator was selected as the default Terminal emulator

Tags: kde, terminator, konsole

I've recently switched to KDE on my Ubuntu 22.04 and in the settings I'd set up Terminator to be the default Terminal emulator.

But whenever I start terminal using Ctrl + Alt + T, the Konsole comes up instead.

How do I change this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: The keyboard shortcut most likely opens up Konsole directly, rather then opening up "a generic terminal, which is set to Konsole by default". You probably have to go change the keyboard shortcut, not sure how to do that on KDE

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, I don't know whether it works for 22.04

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

choose your fav terminal, it will be set as system default

Comment: Thanks. With this I can update the configuration but nevertheless Konsole still launches when I use shortcut.

Comment: Check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts) may works for you too.