# alt key shortcuts in pycharm are not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, shortcut-keys, pycharm

Shortcuts involving the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key are not working in pycharm.

For example the shortcut for "finding usages" on my machine is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but whenever I press this key, my cursor changes from an arrow to a hand (the icon it changes to when you move a window).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use IntelliJ IDEA keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me is described [in this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/412046/488419).

In short: if you've already got used to combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, you can disable/change default Ubuntu shortcuts which are overlapping with default shortcuts used in PyCharm.

Comment: oof, I didn't even think that the system shortcuts could be conflicting. I love my `ALT+Click` to drag windows around... didn't even cross my mind this was conflicting with `ALT+Click` to add carets in PyCharm!

Answer (score 0):

All I would like to say is that the solution is simple:

Turn off **Vim Emulation** in the **Tools** menu