# Ubuntu 16.04 Ctrl+Alt+S doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

In IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> doesn't work. The key map is set on Default for Gnome. How to resolve this issue?

Output for `for d in /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/ /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/ /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/; do dconf dump "$d"; done | grep -iFe '<Control><Alt>S'` is:

```
toggle-shaded=['<Control><Alt>s']
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster I expect to work. When I manually (by mouse open) open `File menu` there is the legend that shortcut is `CTRL-ALT-S`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Done

Comment: @DavidFoerster Disable it. Now it works. Please write an answer to the question to mark it as the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the window manager already captures the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

To unbind it or rebind it to a different key combination

1. open the *Control Center*,
2. navigate to *Keyboard → Shortcuts*,
3. select the *Windows* shortcuts,
4. look for the *Toggle shaded state* shortcut entry and
5. edit it to a different or no key combination.

This applies to at least Unity and GNOME since they both use the same settings entries to determine keyboard shortcut combinations.

It's possible that the key combination is not bound to the same shortcut as in OP's case, in which case you need to look through all shortcut entries for one that has the key combination in question.

Comment: any idea about 18.04 LTS? The `for d in /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/ /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/ /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/; do dconf dump "$d"; done | grep -iFe '<Control><Alt>S'`  does not result in any output.

Comment: @chuckskull: You can always look through the list of keyboard shortcuts manually. There aren’t that many after all. In theory the settings dialogue should unbind previously bound combos if you try to reuse them; thus you can bind the affected combo to something and then unbind it again to also unbind it from any other function. Otherwise could you please open a new question if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: It's nowhere in the list in Ubuntu 20.04 for me. The below `dconf` answer did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In such case `dconf reset /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-shaded` makes a deal.